# How can I retrieve file from external url?

Tags: laravel, file, url, laravel-5

I am trying to develop a small app that enables a user to upload video from URL or user can directly upload video from his/her device. For instance if a user gives a link of a youtube video this should be stored at my storage folder or user can upload video from his Computer drive/ phone storage.

I have completed the upload from device/storage. But unable to do that from external url

```
    $request->validate([
        'video' => 'required',
        'title' => 'required'
    ]);

    if ($request->hasFile('video')) {
        $path = Storage::disk('public')->put('videos', $request->file('video'));
        Video::create([
                'title' => $request->get('title'),
                'video' => $path,
                'user_id' => Auth::user()->id
        ]);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a piece that could help.

```
if (filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)){
    $video_file_data = file_get_contents($url);
    $ext = pathinfo($url, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    Storage::disk('anywhere')->put('path/file.'. $ext, $video_file_data);
}
```

Comment: This stores the entire page of url , not the file. 

$url = $request->get('url');
            if (filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)){
                $video_file_data = file_get_contents($url);
                $ext = pathinfo($url, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
               $path = Storage::disk('public')->put('videos.'.$ext, $video_file_data);